# Div content is not showing in printing

Tags: html, css

I have a div with styling of fixed position. When i am getting print of this div using `"cntr+p"` command then div not showing full content.

> The div is scrollable.

```
<div class="subtask-generate">
 // Too much content in this div.
</div>
```

Css:

```
.subtask-generate {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: is it printing small amount of content ??

Comment: @rudrainnovative, the position attribute is not in css ?

Comment: @ShowStopper, yes getting print of just first page.

Comment: Add some print styles to your css `@media print {}`

Comment: I have updated question, position is fixed.

Comment: check my answer  if it is working.

Comment: @Aaron , What need to add inside media print{}, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this css rule. you just need to add  `overflow: visible;` in your rule for `@media only print`.this should work for you .

```
<style>
@media only print {
   .subtask-generate {
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     overflow: visible;
   }
}
</style>
```

Comment: If i am using this css, but in this case the scrolling not working.

Comment: Thanks @showstopper, its working but also i have changed the position: fixed to position:absolute